# Generating a computationally efficient adjacency matrix using Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am generating an adjacency matrix using `networkx`. For `N=10`, the elapsed time is `0.1 seconds`. Is there a more efficient way to do it? I present the current and expected outputs of elapsed times.

```
import networkx as nx
import time 

N=10


def TicTocGenerator():
    # Generator that returns time differences
    ti = 0           # initial time
    tf = time.time() # final time
    while True:
        ti = tf
        tf = time.time()
        yield tf-ti # returns the time difference

TicToc = TicTocGenerator() # create an instance of the TicTocGen generator

# This will be the main function through which we define both tic() and toc()
def toc(tempBool=True):
    # Prints the time difference yielded by generator instance TicToc
    tempTimeInterval = next(TicToc)
    if tempBool:
        print( "Elapsed time: %f seconds.\n" %tempTimeInterval )

def tic():
    # Records a time in TicToc, marks the beginning of a time interval
    toc(False)

t = time.time()

tic()

################################################################

def pos():
    x, y = 1, N + 3 - 1
    for _ in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
        yield (x, y)
        y -= (x + 2) // (N + 3)
        x = (x + 2) % (N + 3)

G = nx.Graph()
it_pos = pos()
for u in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
    G.add_node(u+1, pos=next(it_pos))
    if u % (2 * N + 1) < N:
        for v in (u - 2 * N - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            if G.has_node(v + 1):
                G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) == N:
        G.add_edge(u + 1, u - N + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) < 2 * N:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    else:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)

nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

################################################################

toc()
```

The current output is

```
Elapsed time: 0.10 seconds.
```

The expected output is

```
Elapsed time: 0.000001 seconds.
```

Comment: i think for this expected improvement the first thing you should do is to not use python, python is good for prototyping code, but it's 50-100 times slower than a precompiled language, and the package you are using is written entirely in python ... which is only as fast as python gets.

Comment: I see...is there a way to bring elapsed time down to ```0.001 seconds``` which is 2 orders of magnitude faster?

Comment: well, it takes around 1 millisecond to make the graph in memory, the rest of the time is drawing it, maybe you don't need to draw it .... or if you are pushing something into production and need fast drawing you could use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) with its C++ API, still don't expect orders of magnitude of improvement, only like 5-20 times faster at best.